# Use one SQL Server trigger that listens on updates of multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database with multiple tables.

All tables contain the same two columns `DataRowModified` (type `datetime`) and `DataRowLastAuthor` (type `nvarchar(MAX)`). And no, I can't put all those columns into a separate table, it's a requirement that each table directly contains those rows.

I wrote the trigger below for the table `Events` to automatically update the values of those two columns whenever a row gets updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Events_UpdateMetadata]
    ON [dbo].[Events]
    FOR UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Events] 
        SET [DataRowModified] = GETDATE(),
            [DataRowLastAuthor] = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
        WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM INSERTED)
    END
```

Now my question is whether I have to copy (and rename) this trigger for every table I have to use it with, or can I somehow write a global trigger that works on all (or a specified set of) tables? It has to know in which table/row the update happened though, because it has to modify it.

What would be the easiest way to implement an automatically maintained `LastAuthor` and `LastModificationDate` column into many tables as described?

Comment: You have a couple of problems in your trigger here. marc_s already discussed the concept you are going for so I will only mention the contents of the trigger here. First you are using two update statements when you only need one. Second, and probably a bigger problem, is that you are not using the inserted table in your code. As posted this will update every single row in the Events table which I highly doubt is what you want. You should probably also use ORIGINAL_LOGIN instead of SUSER_NAME in case of EXECUTE AS.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your comment, I'm still very new to SQL. What do you think about my updated trigger code I edited into my question?

Comment: I would push back on the requirement - either these two columns are pointless or you'll discover that you actually need a full audit trail. Otherwise, consider two updates perform by two users. User A performs a devastating update that has real financial consequences. User B performs a trivial spelling correction. What does your table tell you? Only that User B was the last person to perform some kind of update.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The project is not that critical, its only a program that will manage events and create fliers and other documents from that. Also I'm having this as internship project and the log columns I mentioned are required like this by the boss. But if I did not have those restrictions, I would totally agree with your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trigger in SQL Server is **always** bound to a **single** table - you cannot have "global" triggers or triggers attached to multiple tables at once.

If you need a trigger on your 50 tables - you need to write 50 trigger, one each for every table. No way around this.

The only way to avoid this would be to update those columns in your database layer of your application, so that those values would already be present when you save your row of data. Things like Entity Framework allow such "bulk operations" on multiple entities to e.g. update a last modified date and last user to modify the entity.

Answer (score 2):

> No, But multiple triggers could invoke the same stored procedure.